# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' when using list of integers

Tags: for-loop, typeerror, python-3.3

```
def run_counter(card_list, num_cards):
    hand = functions1.hand_sample(card_list, num_cards)
    hand1 = functions1.hand_shuffle(card_list, num_cards)
    srt_hand = sorted(hand)
    srt_hand1 = sorted(hand1)
    prop_hand = functions1.proper_hand(srt_hand)
    prop_hand1 = functions1.proper_hand(srt_hand1)
    run1 = 0
    i = 0
    for count in range(len(srt_hand)-1):
        if srt_hand[i] == srt_hand[i+1] - 1:
            run1 += 1
    run2 = 0
    i = 0
    for count in range(len(srt_hand1)-1):
        if srt_hand1[i] == srt_hand1[i+1] - 1:
            run2 += 1
    return run1+1, run2+1, prop_hand, prop_hand1
```

I have a hand of cards that I generate, and store in a sorted list 'srt_hand' and 'srt_hand1'. I made a function that should count the length of the runs in the hand. I go to test it but it keeps saying that 'if srt_hand[i] == srt_hand[i+1] - 1:' is an unsupported operand type. Why is that? It doesn't make any sense since I'm indexing a list of integers...

I had this before, with the same sorting technique and it worked (except it stopped after the first run):

```
run1 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(srt_hand)-1 and run1 < 2:
    while i < len(srt_hand)-1 and srt_hand[i] == srt_hand[i+1] - 1:
        if srt_hand[i] == srt_hand[i+1]:
            i += 1
        run1 += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1
run2 = 0
i = 0
while i < len(srt_hand1)-1 and run2 < 2:
    while i < len(srt_hand1)-1 and srt_hand1[i] == srt_hand1[i+1] - 1:
        if srt_hand[i] == srt_hand[i+1]:
            i += 1
        run2 += 1
        i += 1
    i += 1
return run1+1, run2+1, prop_hand, prop_hand1
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a list of integers? Print the types of the elements.

Comment: Also, you seem to have missed the point of the `for` loop. Instead of having that unused `count` variable and manually incrementing and resetting `i`, you should just use `for i in range(len(whatever) - 1)`.

Comment: Oh, very true. Been used to while loops haha

Comment: Also, I'm sure its a list of integers, the hand lists are generated from a fixed list of integers... so there's no way they are anything else. I don't see how sorting the list using sorted() has any implication on the type... since list.sort() returns None, so I shouldn't use that.

Comment: Print the types. It doesn't matter that you're sure it's a list of integers; it's a good idea to do it anyway. Also, while you're at it, a full stack trace would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `sorted` function returns a generator in python3.3, so you can't index it like a list as in `srt_hand[i]` (which will raise an exception).